# Determine whether $x^2 \equiv 667\pmod{919}$ has solutions.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Determine whether $x^2 \equiv 667\pmod{919}$ has solutions.

I'm not asking for an answer since I really want to figure this out, but researching and I can't find anything. Almost every example I find is that a is a perfect number such that $(x-a)(x+a)$, but in here The factors of $667$ are $1,23,29,667$ and $919$ is prime. Any links or hints to get me going?

Comment: Look up Law of Quadratic Reciprocity.

Comment: Will do thanks.

Comment: try it with $x=242$ or $x=677$

Comment: I see that both of them are solutions, but how did you approach them?

Comment: Wikipedia has an article on [Quadratic Residues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$919$ is a prime  $\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ and by the quadratic reciprocity theorem the Legendre symbol $\left(\frac{667}{919}\right)$ can be computed as follows:
$$\left(\frac{667}{919}\right)=\left(\frac{23}{919}\right)\left(\frac{29}{919}\right)=-\left(\frac{-1}{23}\right)\left(\frac{20}{29}\right)=\left(\frac{5}{29}\right)=\left(\frac{-1}{5}\right)=+1$$
hence $x^2\equiv 667\pmod{919}$ has two solutions, namely $\pm242$.

Comment: Just Dr. Sonnhard mentioned, wouldn't $\pm677$ be a solution as well?

Comment: @Killercamin: $\pmod{919}$ to write $\pm 242$ or $\pm 677$ is the same thing, since $242+677\equiv 0$.

Comment: In $\mathbb{F}_{919}$ the polynomial $x^2-667$ cannot have more than two roots, since $\mathbb{F}_{919}$ is a field (a *finite* field, but still a field). An if $\alpha$ is a root then $-\alpha$ is also a root, obviously.

Comment: I see, I was heading with the Legendre (so i guess I was going in the right direction), my only question is that since the Legendre symbol is +1 then a is a quadratic residue modulo of p, right?

Comment: @Killercamin: if $p$ is a prime and $p\nmid a$, $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)=+1$ iff $a$ is a quadratic residue $\pmod{p}$, i.e. if there is some $x\in\mathbb{F}_p$ such that $x^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$, correct.

Comment: Of course the computation of $\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)$ can be performed in many ways, by exploiting quadratic reciprocity / the multiplicativity of Legendre symbol at each step, but the final outcome has to be the same.

Comment: One last question, when I was doing the Legendre by myself, mine ended up being a little bit differently but still with the same outcome. $(\frac{23}{919})(\frac{29}{919})= (-1)^{(22)(918)}(\frac{919}{23})(-1)^{(28)(918)}(\frac{919}{29}) \rightarrow (\frac{22}{23})(\frac{20}{29})= (\frac{11}{23})(\frac{2}{23}) \times (\frac{5}{29})(\frac{4}{29})= -(\frac{11}{23})(\frac{5}{29}) $ Since $(\frac{2}{23})=-1, (\frac{2^2}{29})=1.$

Comment: Similarly, $\gcd(29,86)=\gcd(29,28)=\gcd(1,28)=-1$ or simply $\gcd(29,86)=\gcd(29,-1)=1$. Your approach is fine.

Comment: I see, I know it's too much already but can you verify how I computed the 1 with my Legendre symbol? I left out more information from $(\frac{11}{23}) (\frac{5}{29})$, but it ends up repeating.

Comment: @Killercamin: your computation is fine. I ended up with a single $\left(\frac{5}{29}\right)$ but of course $$-\left(\frac{11}{23}\right)=\left(\frac{23}{11}\right)=\left(\frac{1}{11}\right)=1$$ so we agree.